# Extremely slow MySQL performance after changing client server

Tags: linux, mysql, centos5, magento

I have a Magento web server (CentOS) that uses a crossover cable to connect to a MySQL database server.

The other day, I upgraded the Magento server. I disconnected the crossover cable from the old Magento server and plugged it into the new one. I was able to connect to MySQL, but it took about 90 seconds. When I tried to open the webpage it timed out basically.

Why would this be so slow? What type of caches, etc do I need to clear? I restarted both servers completely just to make sure it wasn't some random service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the ethernet ports on BOTH set to the same speed and duplexing?  If not, you'd have incompatible and problematic transfers between the two systems on this cable.  Another suggestion is to ensure that the cable type is appropriate to the transfer rate being used.

Comment: I can SCP from one machine to the other at well over 100mbps.. Plus a .3ms ping time. I don't think it actually has to do with the speed of the link.